# Move file with > in the name

Tags: bash

I have a number of files which have (roughly) uniform file names, but all files begin with a > in the name, for example:

```
>PAU_unit1.fsa
>PAU_unit2.fsa
.
.
.
>PAU_Kingscliffe.fsa
```

I would like to move all of them to a new directory as in:

```
mv *.fsa newdir/
```

But the > at the beginning of the names is understandably confusing the `mv`. If I pass the `--` flag that I have seen in answers to similar questions, to prevent parsing, the `*` is then ignored as well.

Is there any way to have `mv` (or any other command for that matter) ignore parsing the `>`, but still parse `*` ?

Comment: Redirections are parsed before filename generation occurs; there shouldn't be a problem with your command. (`mv -- *.fsa newdir` should also be fine; the `--` doesn't have any special meaning to the shell, only in how `mv` interprets the arguments passed to it by the shell.)

Comment: I've just realised that the original question is maybe not very clearly phrased. I'd like to achieve the _effect_ of a `mv *` command, but by using the `>` in the file names as my expandable wildcard. i.e. I'd like to move all files something like this (to capture the > at the start since it's a reliable character in the names, but then match anything afterward: `mv >* newdir/`

Comment: Just quote the character: `mv '>'*.fsa newdir/` or `mv \>*.fsa newdir/`. You don't have to quote an entire word, just the characters that need quoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
mv \>*.fsa newdir/
```

Comment: Great thank you, I knew it should be something as simple as escaping the character (though I could have sworn I tried exactly this before with no luck!) but have just tried again and it does indeed do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` is one option:

```
find . -name '*.fsa' -maxdepth 1 -exec mv '{}' newdir/ \;
```

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with `find`, and at a glance I'm guessing the key here is `-maxdepth 1` - what exactly is that doing?

Comment: `-maxdepth 1` stops `find` to traverse to sub-directories as you are trying to move only current directory's files.

Comment: I got the following error, though I copied and pasted your command exactly: `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`

Comment: If `+` is not supported in your `find` then use: **`find . -name '*.fsa' -maxdepth 1 -exec mv '{}' newdir/ \;`**

Comment: @anubhava Since Joe's error message mentions it, I assume it's supported.

Comment: `+` is supported by all `find` that are POSIX compliant. Though, your usage of `{}` is wrong: _The end of the primary expression shall be punctuated by a <semicolon> or by a <plus-sign>. Only a <plus-sign> that immediately follows an argument containing only the two characters "{}" shall punctuate the end of the primary expression. Other uses of the <plus-sign> shall not be treated as special._ See [POSIX `find` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).

Comment: Good point as always @gniourf_gniourf It is edited in answer now.